# Hidden Line Removal algorithm for 3D meshes?

Tags: opengl, graphics, geometry

Given an arbitrary 3D mesh, I'm looking for an algorithm that would perform hidden-line removal in real-time. I'm working in the context of OpenGL, which means that we can take advantage of the Z-Buffer.

I guess that the algorithm should include a solution to the two following problems:

1) Defining which are the "hard-edges" for later-on drawing them using regular OpenGL lines. These "hard-edges" should correspond to edges where the angle between the 2 corresponding faces is above some threshold.

For the sake of simplicity, let's state that it is guaranteed that no more than 2 faces are defined per edge.

The calculation of the "hard-edges" should take place once per mesh, i.e. it is not related to the view-point.

2) Defining the outline of the mesh's silhouette, according to the current view-point. Eventually, this part could be done using classical OpenGL techniques (involving polygon-offset or the stencil-buffer), but it would be preferable to draw the silhouette using regular OpenGL lines, to keep an unified look & feel for all the lines.

For that part, I'm not sure if the vertices of the silhouette should all pass through mesh vertices or not. In any case, for meshes like cubes _ where there is no need for a silhouette (since it is enough to draw only the "hard-edges") _ the algorithm should be smart enough to avoid drawing a "similar line" twice...

Comment: Update: the first problem is known as "crease edge detection". The second problem as "silhouette edge detection".

Comment: And yes, the silhouette is essentially passing through the mesh vertices. By the way, the process of defining the silhouette vertices is a key stage during the computation of "shadow volumes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.  First, you want to draw the lines of the mesh, and second you want to draw a silhouette.  Here is a generic procedure to make this work,

1. Draw the (using triangles) mesh to the depth buffer only by clearing the [color mask](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMask.xml).
2. Turn the color mask back on, switch the [front face](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml), and rescale/offset your mesh by some small percent.  Flipping the front face causes you to only see the inside of the offset mesh, which gets clipped by the depth buffer of the previously drawn mesh.  If you do this right, it should give you a neat looking outline.  Here is an example of this technique: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/Outline_Mode.aspx
3. Finally, draw the edges of the mesh (while keeping the depth buffer intact from the previous two operations) over the existing mesh and shell.

The result is that you will now have all the edges of your mesh drawn, together with a nice silhouette!

EDIT:  After rereading your post a second time, it sounds like you don't want to draw all the edges, only those which occur at a boundary with sufficiently high curvature.  So, to do this, you could do one of the following:

1. Preprocess the edges of your mesh, and cull out all of the edges which link pairs of nearly coplanar faces.  This is easy to check by just comparing the dot products of their normals.  If it sufficiently close to 1, discard that edge from your rendered set.
2. More generally, you can also approximate the curvature of your mesh in screen space.  Doing this is the inverse of computing the so-called screen space ambient occlusion.  (Another neat application of this technique is listed here:  http://zigguratvertigo.com/2011/03/07/gdc-2011-approximating-translucency-for-a-fast-cheap-and-convincing-subsurface-scattering-look/)  Once you have the curvature of your object computed from the depth buffer, you can filter out the lines by only drawing the line fragments that occur on pixels with sufficiently high curvature.

Comment: Mikola, thanks for your help, but this is not solving my problem. I am aware of the existing OpenGL techniques (involving polygon-offset or the stencil-buffer) but they are good only for drawing a silhouette. What I want is also to draw the relevant edges of an arbitrary model. Take a cube for example. I want the algorithm to tell me: draw all the edges except the diagonal ones...

Comment: Mikola, thanks for editing your answer. You proposed to "compare the dot products". I accept that as a partial solution to my problem. What I still need to find out is an efficient way to define the edges (and associated faces) for an arbitrary mesh. Maybe that should be the subject of another question...

Comment: Regarding your proposition of "approximating the curvature of the mesh": it sounds very interesting, but it's a bit above my technical capabilities right now. Thanks anyway for pointing to the GDC 2011 article. Definitely a mind-blowing visual effect!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds [a lot like cel shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel-shaded_animation).

Is that what you are looking for?

The trick is to remove the edges that are blunt. The tricky part is to get the threshold correct, it might be different for each object.

[This article explains more about the algorithm](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/140/lighting-and-shading/cel-shading-r1438) in general it is the fastest [to implement the effect using a pixel shader](http://knol.google.com/k/shader-fx-cell-shading#)

Comment: Erno, thanks for your answer. I'm not interested in the lighting aspects of cell-shading. I am however interested in the "simple edge detection" part of cell-shading, "which uses the dot product between the view vector and the normal for a vertex". The point is that I don't plan to use shaders, so I need to figure out how to do this kind of stuff manually. Part of my problem is right now to find an efficient way to define the edges (and associated faces) for an arbitrary mesh.

Comment: Have a look at the generation of shadow volumes: http://www.sonic.net/~surdules/articles/cg_shadowvolumes/index.html

Comment: Well done and on time! I was about to implement a Quad-Edge data structure for iterating over all the edges, but with your advice, I will definitely seek for eventually less overkill solutions from the "shadow volume" literacy. So thanks again Erno (too bad I can't accept two answers...)

Comment: No worries, It is not about the score, we need answers!

Comment: The source-code was missing in Erno's link, so I'm providing an alternative link, with source-code: http://archive.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1990.asp

Comment: Currently, I'm struggling with the issue of "setting the connectivity between the faces". So far, most of the algorithms I found from the Shadow Volume literature are very ineffective. I'm hopping that the Quad-Edge data structure will help...

Comment: Another problem is how the "faces without trivial neighbors" are treated. For creating a Shadow Volume, it is not a problem to have many such faces. But for drawing a silhouette, one must really make efforts to avoid them as much as possible. Here again, I'm hopping that the Quad-Edge data structure will help...

Comment: Yes you are correct but I see no way of optimizing that other than trying to design/generate 'good' models...

Comment: The problem is that I'm working with dynamic models generated via CSG (boolean operations). So far, I can't build a valid Quad-Edge structure out of them using Heckbert's code: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/2001/pub/src/a2/quadedge.html